# hidesBackButton doesn't seem to work on ios 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

How do I hide my back button on iOS 7?

I tried replacing it:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:homeButton];
```

and hiding it:

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Both used to work but don't anymore on devices using iOS 7

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: iOS7 is under NDA. Ask about this on the Apple Developer Forums https://devforums.apple.com/